# Elasticsearch : How to use multiple filter and calculation in aggregations?

Tags: php, elasticsearch, kibana

I'm trying to do a function on kibana.
I have an index with orders with some fields :
`datetime1`, `datetime2` with format : `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm`

First I have to check if `datetime1` exist.
Secondly I have to check the difference between this 2 datime `datetime2 - datetime1`
To finish I have to put the result in differents aggs if the difference is:

- less than 24h
- between 24 and 48h
- 48 - 72
- ....

What I tried :

```
GET orders/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "test1": {
      "filters": {
        "filters": {
          "exist_datetime1": {
            "exists": {
              "field": "datetime1"
            }
          },
          "24_hours": {
            "script": {
              "script": {
                "source": "doc['datetime2'].value - doc['datetime1'].value < 24",
                "lang": "painless"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

How can I do multiple filter and do a subtraction between date ?
Thank for your help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a good start, however, I think you need something slightly different. Here is an attempt at providing the ranges your need using the [`range` aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-range-aggregation.html#_script) powered by your script.

You need to make sure both date fields have values (`query` part) and then you can define the buckets you need (`< 24h`, `24h - 48h`, etc)

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "exists": {
            "field": "datetime1"
          }
        },
        {
          "exists": {
            "field": "datetime2"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "ranges": {
      "range": {
        "script": {
          "lang": "painless",
          "source": "(doc['datetime2'].value.millis - doc['datetime1'].value.millis) / 3600000"
        },
        "ranges": [
          {
            "to": 24,
            "key": "< 24h"
          },
          {
            "from": 24,
            "to": 48,
            "key": "24h-48h"
          },
          {
            "from": 48,
            "key": "> 48h"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank for the answer, it works very well !
So to use filter it's better using them in the query instead of aggs ?

Comment: Great it helped! Yes, the filter in the query part will reduce the set of documents on which the aggregations is run.